# How to inject doctrine repository to service in ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I need to inject my post repository in my post service. I have a `PostController`, `PostEntity`, `PostServiceInterface` and `PostRepository`.

My post repository contains DQL with methods like `findAll()`, `find($id)`, etc...

In my `PostServiceInterface` I have some methods like `find`, `findAll`.

Now I want to access to repository to get results from my service. I do not want to write queries directly in service. I try to inject the service into `__construct` using DI but that doesn't work.

Can someone provide an example on how to do this?

I am using Zend Framework 2 with DoctrineORMModule.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is writing a custom `PostServiceFactory` to inject `PostRepository` to the `PostService` via constructor injection.

For example:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service\Factory;

use Application\Service\PostService;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class PostServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Creates and returns post service instance.
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $sm
     * @return PostService
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sm)
    {
        $repository = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->getRepository('Application\Entity\PostService');

        return new PostService($repository);
    }
}
```

You also need to change the `PostService`'s constructor signature like below:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service;

use Application\Repository\PostRepository;

class PostService
{
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(PostRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
}
```

Finally, in your `module.config.php` you also need to register your factory in the service manager config:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Application\Service\PostService' => 'Application\Service\Factory\PostServiceFactory',
    )
)
```

Now, you can get the `PostService` via the service locator in your controller like below:

```
$postService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Service\PostService');
```

The `PostRepository` will be automatically injected into the returned service instance as we coded in our factory.

Comment: Is this really the approach you need to take with the ZF di container?  The Symfony container allows you to define a factory service using the entity manager and then calling getRepository on it.  No need for a hard coded PostServiceFactory.  Seems strange that ZF does not have something similar.

Comment: @Cerad, making the class dependent on the `EntityManager` is also possible, but it is not good design. Ivke said the service needs a `ObjectRepository`, so you should also inject this class and not some parent class. If you inject the `EntityManager` you are still not sure if the `EntityManager` can actually deliver the right repository class...

Comment: @Wilt, I am not suggesting that the entity manager be injected.  My comment was that in Symfony, you can define a repository as a service and then inject as needed like any other dependency.  No need for a PostServiceFactory class at all.  Look here for an example of what the service definition looks like in Symfony: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394831/sylius-how-to-inject-request-arguments-in-custom-productrepository

Comment: @cerad there are definitely alternative solutions exist in zf2 like initializers and delegator factories. Initializers does setter injections (like the answer you mentioned and symfony) however it has a minor performance drawback because service locator checks every service instanance to inject necessary dependencies. Is there any built-in solution exist in symfony for constructor injection?