# Sylius: How to inject (request) arguments in custom ProductRepository?

Tags: php, symfony, service, arguments, sylius

I want to override the method **createByTaxonPaginator()** so that the **indexByTaxon()** method gives back sorted results. That new method should use *Request* to get the *sort* Get-Parameter.
For ordering the searchresults i found the service and overrode that as following:

```
sylius_search.repository:
    class: ShopBundle\Entity\SearchIndexRepository
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@sylius.repository.product', '@request_stack']
```

maybe that is not a good practice, i dont know. But it works...
unfortunately i didnt find any service definition for sylius.repository.product to have a look on the required args.

in my config i have following:

```
sylius_product:
    classes:
        product:
            model: ShopBundle\Entity\Product # My Own Entity
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\ProductController
            repository: ShopBundle\Entity\ProductRepository
            # is there an option for injecting arguments?
            form:
                default: ShopBundle\Form\Type\ProductType
            translation:
                model: ShopBundle\Entity\ProductTranslation
                form:
                    default: ShopBundle\Form\Type\ProductTranslationType
```

is there an option for injecting args which i didn't know? Here the Repo which extends the default one and overloads the Method **createByTaxonPaginator()**

```
 <?php

namespace ShopBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository as BaseProductRepository;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\TaxonInterface;

class ProductRepository extends BaseProductRepository
{

    /**
     * Create paginator for products categorized under given taxon.
     * Modified: Sorting of Taxon listing added
     *
     * @param TaxonInterface $taxon
     * @param array          $criteria
     *
     * @return \Pagerfanta\Pagerfanta
     */


    public function createByTaxonPaginator(TaxonInterface $taxon, array $criteria = array())
    {
        // Here i want to have the Request $request arg..
        $queryBuilder = $this->getCollectionQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
            ->innerJoin('product.taxons', 'taxon')
            ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
                'taxon = :taxon',
                ':left < taxon.left AND taxon.right < :right'
            ))
            ->setParameter('taxon', $taxon)
            ->setParameter('left', $taxon->getLeft())
            ->setParameter('right', $taxon->getRight())
            ->orderBy('translation.name') // ... to get this dynamic
        ;

        $this->applyCriteria($queryBuilder, $criteria);

        return $this->getPaginator($queryBuilder);
    }

}
```

Comment: So is your question "how to define sylius.repository.product"?

Comment: No, my question ist "how to inject the request as argument to my custom productRepository service?" This service has the id: sylius.repository.product. I hope i dont confuse you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question but here is an example of defining a repository service and then injecting an additional service.  You cannot use constructor injection for the request stack because the repository itself is created using the entity manager as a factory:

```
sylius.repository.product:
  class:  ShopBundle\Entity\ProductRepository
  factory: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', 'getRepository']
  arguments:
    - 'ShopBundle\Entity\Product'
  calls: [[setRequestStack, ['@request_stack']]]
```

You will need to add setRequestStack to your custom repository.

You might also want to rethink the whole notion of making these services depend on the request object.  Tends to get messy.  Might be better to pass the sort parameter as an argument in your methods calls.

Update 13 Sep 2019:
This answer is obsolete.  In most cases you will want to derive your repository from the ServiceEntityRepository and then inject the RequestStack into the constructor.  This answer is still valid for 2.x.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Cerad. Unfortunately now i get the error "Class "ShopBundle\Entity\ProductRepository" sub class of "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository" is not a valid entity or mapped super class." 

I have worked around by adding Request with "use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;" and in my method i set the $request manually with: $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

Comment: My bad.  The argument should have been ShopBundle\Entity\Product and not ShopBundle\Entity\ProductRepository.  Fixed the answer.  And you really don't want to use Request::createFromGlobals.  All kinds of bad things can happen.  Which is why I suggest not using the request at all.

Comment: Thank you again, that solved the problem! The cause of using a $_GET var for sorting is, that i implemented a small select at the bottom `search_form.html.twig` Template. A user can now select there sorting in the same way he selects other search / filter options. All these come over $_GET. So i thought it would be ok to put in another value in the same way. The logic is very simple, it tests if the field is  identical to one of the (two) fields specified and then i write the queryBuilder things without taking the $_GET vars. Therefore xss is not possible. Maybe i forget some important thing?